# Use SAP APO SNP Optimizer programmatically

Tags: abap, cplex, sap-apo

I found an [article](http://www.scmfocus.com/sapplanning/2009/07/25/snp-optimizer/) on the internet telling that SAP Advanced Planer and Optimizer (APO) uses the ILOG CPLEX optimizer under the hood.

Can you tell me whether it is possible to access the optimizer programmatically in order to solve custom optimization problems?